# Firestore basic question: How to avoid N+1 requests on join

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how I could structure my database in order to avoid doing N requests for all the joins I want to do.
Firebase gets quite expensive when you do a lot of requests.

Let's say I have a todo app, 400 todo to display for my whole company.

I want to display them on the home page, and each todo is assigned to a user.

I have two collections:

```
- Todos
--> id
--> ...
--> user_id

- Users
--> id
```

Each time a users displays the home page, I will have 401 requests sent to just get the user name assigned to each todo.

A solution could be to keep the username inside each todo, but I would have to updates all todos each time a user is updated.

What is the best solution to minimize the number of requests, knowing I can't load all the users and todo (the database is too big)?

Comment: It sounds like you've already identified the tradeoffs in minimizing the number of requests, if that's what you really want to optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An `IN`/`OR` logical operator is on the Firestore team's radar](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321), but I don't think it's possible today.

I think Doug's comment is correct, and it can be restated like this: You'll probably have to choose between fast reads (and store user information in each Todo object, which will slow down writes) or fast writes (and increase the number of requests, slowing down reads).

I suspect that it would be better in the long run to just store the relevant User information (first and last name, username, etc) in each Todo object. Changing your user details is probably going to be a fairly rare occurrence, so it's probably more acceptable to make that a longer process.

You could also offload the function that performs the modification to each of the User's Todo objects to a Cloud Function, so the user doesn't have to wait for the process to complete.